# Set RecordReader context as a paragraph in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I wanted to write my own RecordReader that returns context as a whole paragraph instead of a line as in TextInputFormat.

I tried the following function but definitely its **way-off**

```
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (key == null) {
        key = new LongWritable();
    }
    key.set(pos);
    if (value == null) {
        value = new Text();
    }
    value.clear();
    final Text endline = new Text("\n");
    int newSize = 0;

        Text v = new Text();
        while (v!= endline) {
            value.append(v.getBytes(),0, v.getLength());
            value.append(endline.getBytes(),0, endline.getLength());
            if (newSize == 0) {
                break;
            }
            pos += newSize;
            if (newSize < maxLineLength) {
                break;
            }
        }
    if (newSize == 0) {
        key = null;
        value = null;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "way-off"? What issue are you having?

Comment: Also you'll need to find a way to define paragraph boundaries - are they empty line separated, or is the first sentence of a new paragraph indented (tab, or whitespace)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to got to the effort of writing your own RecordReader. Instead just extend the TextInputFormat and change the delimiter. The following is the library code for TextInputFormat with just the delimiter changed:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

public class ParagraphInputFormat
extends TextInputFormat {
    private static final String PARAGRAPH_DELIMITER = "\r\n\r\n";

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>
    createRecordReader(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context) {
        String delimiter = PARAGRAPH_DELIMITER;
        byte[] recordDelimiterBytes = null;
        if (null != delimiter) {
            recordDelimiterBytes = delimiter.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
        }
        return new LineRecordReader(recordDelimiterBytes);
    }
}
```